# Не появляются блоки, при нажатии на кнопку JS

Tags: javascript

Решил реализовать появление 2ух блоков, реализовывал через `classList`, но 1 блок не появляется, а второй появляется, но без анимации, в консоли ошибки отсутствуют, с чем это связанно?

```js
function tourActive() {
  var tour_red = document.getElementById("tour_red");
  var tour = document.getElementById("tour");
  var display = window.getComputedStyle(tour).visibility;
  var tStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(tour, null) : tour.currentStyle;
  if (tStyle.visibility === "hidden") {
    tour.classList.add("active_tour");
    tour_red.classList.add("red_active");
  } else {
    tour.classList.remove("active_tour");
    tour_red.classList.remove("red_active");
  }
}
```

```css
#tour {
  background: #1b2550;
  width: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  /*display: none;*/
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: all .4s;
}

.active_tour {
  width: 500px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  transition: all .4s;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#tour_red {
  background: #fb516e;
  height: 46px;
}

.red_active {
  width: 15px;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="tour">NEW TOUR</h4>
<div id="tour_red"></div>
<div class="tour_green"><button onclick="tourActive()"></button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в приоритете css селектором. Селектор по id "сильнее", чем по классу, соответственно значения из селекторов `active_tour` и `red_active` не применялись.

И еще, что бы анимация работала, надо что бы было первоначальное значение и конечное. В случае с `#tour_red` у вас не было начального значения `width`.

```js
function tourActive() {
  var tour_red = document.getElementById("tour_red");
  var tour = document.getElementById("tour");
  var display = window.getComputedStyle(tour).visibility;
  var tStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(tour, null) : tour.currentStyle;
  if (tStyle.visibility === "hidden") {
    tour.classList.add("active_tour");
    tour_red.classList.add("red_active");
  } else {
    tour.classList.remove("active_tour");
    tour_red.classList.remove("red_active");
  }
}
```

```css
#tour {
  background: #1b2550;
  width: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  /*display: none;*/
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: all .4s;
}

#tour.active_tour {
  width: 500px;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  transition: all .4s;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#tour_red {
  background: #fb516e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 46px;
}

#tour_red.red_active {
  width: 15px;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

```html
<h4 id="tour">NEW TOUR</h4>
<div id="tour_red"></div>
<div class="tour_green"><button onclick="tourActive()"></button></div>
```